# HTML code doesn't work on IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, sharepoint, browser

I have a question about making only part of attached picture linked to something. My code does work on Chrome/Firefox but unfortunately it doesn't on IE (11). I have to fix it, cause due to it is a Sharepoint site, my company recommends to use Microsoft browser. Below you can find my code. 
Thank you for any help.

```html
<div style="text-align: right; position: relative;">
  <img alt="Map.png" src="/sites/AAFAA0567/PublishingImages/default/Map.png" style="margin: 5px; width: 586px; height: 615px; font-size: 10.66px;" />​
  <a href="mailto:xxx" style="left: 252px; top: 3px; width: 83px; height: 83px; display: block; position: absolute;"></a>
  <a href="mailto:xxx" style="left: 19px; top: 475px; width: 88px; height: 49px; display: block; position: absolute;"></a>
  <a href="mailto:xxx" style="left: 135px; top: 475px; width: 88px; height: 49px; display: block; position: absolute;"></a>
  <a href="mailto:xxx" style="left: 71px; top: 537px; width: 88px; height: 49px; display: block; position: absolute;"></a>
  <a href="asd.com" style="left: 71px; top: 410px; width: 88px; height: 49px; display: block; position: absolute;"></a>
  <a href="asd.com" style="left: 351px; top: 390px; width: 232px; height: 220px; display: block; position: absolute;"></a>
</div>
```